# Отсортировать массив по возврастанию

Tags: php

Есть двумерный массив.

```
Array ( [2] => Array ( [name] => Акустические системы [category_id] => 299 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Звуковое оборудование [category_id] => 79 ) )
```

Как отсортировать его по возрастанию, но только по первому индексу?

```
asort($flowers);
```

сортирует по первому и второму индексу? а нужно только по первому

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php думаю это вам поможет

Comment: Что здесь __первый__ и __второй__ индексы?